# Java(android): How to I split a string by every two line breaks?

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have tried using string.split("\n\n") but it does not work. Anyone has any solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should *escape* the `\` with another `\` like this:

```
string.split("\\n\\n");
```

Another way is using system default line separator:

```
string.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"{2}");
```

or you can try mix this:

```
string.split("(\\r\\n|"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+")+");
```

`split` need RegExp, so you can try variants for your problem.

And don't forget that sometimes new line is not only `\n` symbol, for Windows files it can be `\r\n` char sequence.

Comment: Three years later. So helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You should *escape* the `\` with another `\` so try :-

```
string.split("\\n\\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the escape sequence `\`:

```
string.split("\\n\\n");
```